# PHP file access time not updating as expected

Tags: php

I am writing to a log file in PHP.

If it has only been a few seconds since last `fwrite`, I wish to append to the log file; if more than 10 seconds, it is a new test and the `fopen` context should be 'w' (overwrite).

This was my plan:

```
$ff = '_ax_test.log';
$wm = (time() - filemtime($ff) >= 10) ? 'w': 'a'; //write mode (append or write)
$fp=fopen($ff, $wm);
```

However, the results are unexpected -- $wm evaluates always > 10, always. Even for immediately subsequent writes.

As a test, I left the file alone for several minutes, and then ran this TWICE, with a 90-second break in between:

```
$ff = '_ax_test.log';
$tt = time();
$ft = filemtime($ff);
$dd = $tt - $ft;
$wm = ($dd <= 500) ? 'a': 'w'; //write mode (append or write)

$fp=fopen($ff, 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'First write: ' .$wm. '   ('.$dd.' = tt:[' .$tt. '] - ft[' .$ft. '] )' ."\n\r"); 
fclose($fp);

sleep(6);

$ff = '_ax_test.log';
$tt = time();
$ft = filemtime($ff);
$dd = $tt - $ft;
$wm = ($dd <= 500) ? 'a': 'w'; //write mode (append or write)

$fp=fopen($ff, 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'First write: ' .$wm. '   ('.$dd.' = tt:[' .$tt. '] - ft[' .$ft. '] )' ."\n\r"); 
fclose($fp);
```

**Result:**

```
First write: a   (318 = tt:[1422045622] - ft[1422045304] )

Next write: a   (324 = tt:[1422045628] - ft[1422045304] )

---- 90-second delay ----

First write: a   (94 = tt:[1422045722] - ft[1422045628] )

Next write: a   (100 = tt:[1422045728] - ft[1422045628] )
```

There is exactly a 6-second delay between the first and second fwrites, but the filetime on the file doesn't seem to change when it should.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Your question is about modification time, not access time (that's the time the file was last read).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For performance reasons, rather than execute a disk access every time you need information about a file, PHP caches the file details... which includes the last modified time of that file.

If you need to override this behaviour, use [clearstatcache()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)